# Fonts don't look as sharp after re installing windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts, cleartype

I have reinstalled windlows 7 on my Lenovo thinkpad T400 laptop.

When I go into sites like [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) 
the math fonts look less sharp and are harder to read, comparing to what I had before.

I have installed all windows updates, and the resolution is the same as it was, I have also tried to set cleartype (though I admit almost all the pictures looked the same and I didn't really know that to choose).

The problem appears in both firefox and chrome.

Does anyone have any idea on how to improve how the fonts look ?

any help is greeatly appericiated!

Comment: The fonts also look a bit less bold

Comment: Are you sure you installed proper graphics drivers and that you are running your display in its native (maximum) resolution?

Comment: @Rain - I am using 1920x1080 on my Dell U2312HM (23") screen. I think its OK, no ? Windows update did download something that had U2312HM in its name, probably some kind of driver.

Comment: @Belgi: Is ClearType turned on and have you tried adjusting it as per your preferences? (Just type ClearType in the Start Menu Search box.)